# What is the best mechanism for controlling a character in a 2D Android game?

Tags: 2d, android, rpg, movement, control

Im developing a 2D RPG for Android where the character can move up, down, left, and right like in top-down RPGs like Pokemon.

What is the best input mechanism to use to control the character? A virtual joystick seems a bit to complicated for just straight movement.

Comment: This question isn't constructive in its current form, since the "best" way to control an RPG character on an Android device is entirely subjective. You should specify conditions for what would qualify as the best method.

Comment: And what's wrong with a D-Pad?

Comment: "A digital stick seems a bit to complicated for just straight movement." elaborate please.

Comment: Best is very subjective.

Comment: Also do not forget to account for the multi-touch capabilities of phones. It can add additional complexities if you are also adding A B buttons for input

Comment: I think it is a very good question actually, as modern touch screen displays should have another way of control then the traditional arrow keys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most responsive and familiar mechanism is the physical D-Pad on the Xperia Play device; you could follow Mojang's example and target your game at that device. This would additionally provide support to any devices with a physical D-Pad, since the Play's D-Pad uses the standard [D-Pad key codes](http://www.ixplora.com/develop-gaming-apps-xperia-play-gamepad/). This includes trackballs like the one found on the Nexus One; for those devices you may want to provide an option to keep walking in the last direction they pressed until told otherwise.

If your goal is broad device compatibility, the equivalent would be a virtual joystick, since all Android devices [are required to have a touch screen](http://source.android.com/compatibility/overview.html) before they can install apps from the Android Market. If you're relying on a touch screen, however, I recommend you move the character to whichever point the user touches on the screen.

As Zoot mentioned in the comments, there is another option you may wish to support: bluetooth gamepads such as the [iControlPad](http://icontrolpad.com/). That gamepad in particular maps the [D-Pad controls](http://icontrolpad.com/downloads/iCP_operations4.pdf) to WASD key inputs, though others may vary.

Comment: +1 For D-pad suggestion. I don't agree with the moving the character to wherever they touch though, mainly because it means they have to add in some sort of path-finding.

Comment: @Noctrine I agree that it'd be extra work, but pathfinding is pretty common and I mentioned it in case their game already uses it somewhere else. I admit it's a selfish recommendation because I prefer it in games I play.

Comment: Another option for D-Pad support would be supporting bluetooth game controllers like the iControlPad in addition to the native control method.